# Simply nginx reverse proxy from localhost:80 to localhost:8080 not working

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, reverse-proxy

im learning reverse proxy w/ nginx for the first time, and the following isnt working for me
im trying to reroute requests from http://localhost to an api server i have running at http://localhost:8080

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

when i hit http://localhost, I simply get shown the welcome to nginx splash screen.
if i hit http://localhost:8080, i see my api

I have a node express service running at :8080, which i can hit manually, but shouldn't http://localhost be proxied there too?

Comment: Did you reload or restart `nginx` after the change? Did you try `nginx -t` to see if there was a config issue?

Comment: Yep, did both, to no avail yet.

Comment: no server name so I would guess the `default` config is taking the request. Remove it or give this one a `server_name`

Comment: I added an answer that shows how I solved it... but I don't know why :80 doesnt work but [::]:80 does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I setup a nginx domain that forwards requests to a node server, it looks like this, for the `server_name`, you can use `localhost` as a parameter for accessing it via localhost. You can also pass `default_server` to make this the default server config.

**Note:** Only one active config can contain `default_server` otherwise Nginx will throw errors.

**Note:** When using `default_server`, Nginx will catch `localhost` in that server config. Otherwise you need to specify `localhost` in the list of `server_name`'s (separated by a space).

```sh
server {
  # Setup the domain name(s)
  server_name example.com;
  listen 80 default_server;

  # If you would like to gzip your stuff
  gzip on;
  gzip_min_length 1;
  gzip_types *;

  # Setup the proxy
  # This will forward all requests to the server
  # and then it will relay the servers response back to the client
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out that adding this to my nginx.conf fixes the issue:

```
listen [::]:80;
```

For some reason `listen 80;` doesn't catch my http://localhost requests.